# How to preserve namespace prefixes in a Jena TDB dataset?

Tags: java, namespaces, dataset, rdf, jena

I am using Jena TDB (1.1.1) to store a set of named graphs. Everything works fine but whenever I retrieve a named graph from the the dataset, all the namespace prefix information is lost. Is there a way to preserve the namespace prefixes in the original RDF graph.

Following code snippet shows the issue.

```
@Test
public void testPreserveNsPrefixes(){

    String modelText = "@prefix ro:    <http://purl.org/wf4ever/ro#> ." +
            "@prefix ore:   <http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/> ." +
            "@prefix ldp:   <http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#> ." +
            "<http://example.org/ro> a ore:Aggregation , ro:ResearchObject , ldp:DirectContainer .\n" ;

    // Build the RDF graph
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(modelText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(stream, null, "TURTLE");
    System.out.println("NS prefix count: " + model.getNsPrefixMap().size());

    //Create a dataset
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("test");

    // Add the RDF graph to the dataset
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE) ;
    try {
        dataset.addNamedModel("http://example.org/ro", model);
        dataset.commit() ;
    } finally {
        dataset.end() ;
    }

    //Read the RDF graph again
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try{
        Model model2 = dataset.getNamedModel("http://example.org/ro");
        model2.write(System.out, "TURTLE");
        System.out.println("NS prefix count: " + model2.getNsPrefixMap().size());
    } finally {
        dataset.end();
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
    NS prefix count: 3
    <http://example.org/ro>
        a       <http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#DirectContainer> ,
                <http://purl.org/wf4ever/ro#ResearchObject> ,
                <http://www.openarchives.org/ore/terms/Aggregation> .
    NS prefix count: 0
```

I think is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777907/jena-prefixmapping-base-namespace-missing-when-model-is-a-named-model-obtained) though I don't think it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Discussion about this on the Jena users list:  http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201501.mbox/%3CCAAOEr1my_d4Wzk-FEn25VJFbWJefpZwNTgfJJznMavcm9Z7wfg%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Fixed (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-860)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that the answer isn't lost if the comments get deleted, [AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091817/how-to-preserve-namespace-prefixes-in-a-jena-tdb-dataset#comment44565515_28091817) that this was [discussed on the Jena user's mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201501.mbox/%3CCAAOEr1my_d4Wzk-FEn25VJFbWJefpZwNTgfJJznMavcm9Z7wfg%40mail.gmail.com%3E), and resolved in issue [JENA-860, *Adding a graph does not add prefixes*](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-860).

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaTaylor. As this is about a specific system (hence a bit off-plot for SO?) I used comments. As this is now sorted, a single answer seems good.